# Why a string is interned that is created via constructor and with a char[]?

Tags: c#, .net, string, string-interning

I was sure that this would output false, but [actually](https://dotnetfiddle.net/o0YGI8) it outputs true:

```
string foo = new string("foo".ToCharArray());
Console.WriteLine(string.IsInterned(foo) != null); // true
```

I thought that creating it already via constructor would prevent string interning. But even using a `char[]` causes it to be interned. What is the reason or what is my error in reasoning?

Comment: `string.IsInterned` checks by contents and not by instance.  Try `string s = "foo"; Console.WriteLine(string.IsInterned(String.Concat("oof".Reverse())) != null);` and then comment out the assignment to `s`. You can verify with `Object.ReferenceEquals` that `foo` and `new string("foo".ToCharArray())` will not be the same instance (whereas they will be for `String.Intern(new string("foo").ToCharArray())`).

Comment: @Jeroen more specifically, it is a lookup to *find* the interned version (if there is one) from a potential string, so that code can prefer using interned versions than allocating (or drop a newly created transient string on the floor for the GC to find, using the interned version instead).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Literal strings are interned. And you have the literal `foo` in your source code.

Comment: I thought it would matter how you initialize the string, if as literal or via constructor. But my mistake was that `IsInterned` will not check if the passed string instance is in the intern-table as reference but as value(makes sense if i think about it).